# how to change silex form factory name attribute

Tags: forms, symfony, input, silex

How do i change the default name attribute for an input in my form that is created using the form factory?

here is an example of the simple form i am using:

```
$form = $app['form.factory']->createBuilder('form')
   ->add('image','file)
   ->add('longitude', 'hidden')
   ->add('latitude', 'hidden')
   ->getForm();
```

i have tried putting the attributes into an array without successfully changing the name, although with this method i could change the label or class etc:

```
->add('latitude', 'text', array('attr'=>array("name"=>'newname')))
```

it seems like a very simple request to be able to change the name of an input, so you would have thought there would be an obvious way to do it. With the code above it would still show the name as `name=form[latitude]`

Answer (score 0):

Use createNamedBuilder instead createBuilder to overwrite the fields name. The name will be the first argument in add function.

```
$personal_form = $app['form.factory']->createNamedBuilder(null, 'form')
        ->add('name', 'text', array(
            'label' => 'Nombre',
            'data' => 'Nombre'
        ))
        ->add('surname', 'text', array(
            'label' => 'Apellidos',
            'data' => 'Apellidos'
        ))
        ->add('email', 'email', array(
            'label' => 'E-mail',
            'data' => 'E-mail'
        ))
        ->getForm();
```